# JQuery JSON callback not triggered

Tags: jquery, json, yii, callback

I am using Yii Framework and try to enable CStarRating on my gridview. In output HTML source I have the following:

```
<tr class="odd">
  <td>Bob</td><td>
    <span class="rating" id="6">
    <input id="6_0" value="1" type="radio" name="6" />
    <input id="6_1" value="2" type="radio" name="6" />
    <input id="6_2" value="3" type="radio" name="6" />
    <input id="6_3" value="4" type="radio" name="6" />
    <input id="6_4" value="5" type="radio" name="6" />
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td>Peter</td>
    <span class="rating" id="9">
    <input id="9_0" value="1" type="radio" name="9" />
    <input id="9_1" value="2" type="radio" name="9" />
    <input id="9_2" value="3" type="radio" name="9" />
    <input id="9_3" value="4" type="radio" name="9" />
    <input id="9_4" value="5" type="radio" name="9" />
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And in HTML body I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery('#6 > input').rating({'callback':function(){
                url = "clients/update";
                jQuery.getJSON(url, {id_client: '6', val: $(this).val()},
                function() {
                   if (data.status !== "success"){
                        alert("error");
                   }});}});
    jQuery('#9 > input').rating({'callback':function(){
                url = "clients/update";
                jQuery.getJSON(url, {id_client: '9', val: $(this).val()},
                function() {
                   if (data.status !== "success"){
                        alert("error");
                   }});}});

  });
</script>
```

But when I clicked on the star nothing happened. I am new to JQuery and JSON so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Firstly: Please don't use a number as Id.

Comment: Thank you, I have concat a string in front now but still nothing happened. I think I might need some script for boydy onLoad but I am not sure :(

Comment: Put an alert in click function, and see if click event is fired or not.

Comment: Sorry but where is the click function?

Comment: Sorry. I meant your rating callbacks. Are they being executed?

Answer (score 0):

Forget HTML and jQuery. Using Yii you have this line(or something like it) calling the Rating Stars:

```
$this->widget('CStarRating',array('name'=>'rating'));
```

If you whant to put a `CallBack` on your `Rating Stars`, you add the callback in the options array, like this:

```
$this->widget('CStarRating',array('name'=>'rating','callback'=>'myFunctionCallBack'));
```

This callback will execute when the stars are clicked ([see this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStarRating#callback-detail)).

The Yii `CStarRating` is a widget based on `jQuery Star Rating`, everything you do with the jQuery extension, you can do with the Yii widget. So take a [look here](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating) for more indormation about the extension.

If you whant to see more about the widget(I recommend that), look the documentation [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStarRating).

Some exemples of using the widget:

Some Properties:

```
<?php
$this->widget('CStarRating',array(
            'name'=>'rating_1',
            'value'=>'4',
            'minRating'=>1,
            'maxRating'=>10,
            'starCount'=>10,
            ));
?>
```

With Ajax:

```
<?php
$this->widget('CStarRating',array(
    'name'=>'star_rating_ajax',
    'callback'=>'
        function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "'.Yii::app()->createUrl('cstarrating/ajax').'",
                    data: "star_rating=" + $(this).val(),
                    success: function(data){
                                $("#mystar_voting").html(data);
                        }})}'
  ));
echo "<br/>";
echo "<div id='mystar_voting'></div>";
?>
```

For more exemples, you can see [this article](http://demo.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework/cstarrating), will help yo.

Comment: Thank you so much for spending time to help. In fact, my problem is more complicated. For a single CActiveRecord then that's true, but I am trying to enable voting on CGridView. Please see this: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/57769-problem-with-ajax-and-jquerygetjson-callback/. I would be grateful for any suggestion. Thank you again!